# My VSTS build definition for coded ui test is not creating Test result folder?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've created a build definition for my coded ui test.  I'm not seeing the TestResults folder with the Out folder that is created.  My test is failing because these folder are not being created before I start the test.  In the Out folder there are files that my test use.  After the test fails, I see the command prompt window on the screen by DTAExecuti8onhost.exe with the strings for the texts Results File: with the path of the results folder but when i go to look for this i dont see the folder or the file of the test results file ending in .trx?

My questions is where in the build definition process do i need to set this or do i need to change my code so i'm not looking in the out folder.  I'd rather not change my code but will if this cannot be done. Or my last thinking is do i need to change my build step or add another step for this to occur.

Here is my build definition process.

1. Get sources
2. NuGet restore
3. Build solution
4. Copy Files to:
5. Copy files from
6. Deploy TestAgent on :
7. Run Tests
8. Publish Artifacts :

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please put the error message here? Did you use and test setting or runsetting files?

Comment: Hi Tingting0929-MSFT i did not get an error message, I'm using a test settings file.

Comment: I did a test  and find the 'Run Functional Test' step doesn't generate `Out` folder under `Test Result` folder.  I think this maybe because the  'Run Functional Test' step is using the MSTest.exe to run test. But Visual Studio 2015 is using VSTest.exe to run test. Maybe you could use 'Visual Studio Test' step, this has the `Out` folder.

Comment: Thanks Tingting0929-MSFT for your reply.  It seems that those folders are quickly deleted when the test starts.  I have altered my code and just deployed the files that i needs.  Tahnks ~W